# How to filter data based on two custom filters in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two custom filters, I want to filter my data using both these custom filters. But i faced the problem, If I used one by one then they work good, But when I try to use both filters at the same time then no output. My code is as follow:

```
<script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
     myApp
.filter('selectedTags', function() {
    return function(postdata, tags) {
        return postdata.filter(function(task) {

            for (var i in task.tarn_list) {
                if (tags.indexOf(task.tarn_list[i]) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        });
    };
})
.filter('selectedDep', function() {
    return function(postdata, tags) {
        return postdata.filter(function(task) {

            for (var i in task.deployment) {
                if (tags.indexOf(task.deployment[i]) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        });
    };
})
.controller('PostList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
           var jsonFile='../../json.php';
           $http.get(jsonFile).success(function(data) {
            $scope.postdata = data;
           });
           $scope.useMakes=[]
           $scope.checkBoxModel={
                    search:[],
                    ddsearch:[]
                };
           $scope.totalFeatures=features;
           $scope.deployment=all_deployment;
        }]);
</script>
```

My div is as follow on which I want to apply filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in postdata | selectedDep:checkBoxModel.ddsearch | selectedTags:checkBoxModel.search" >
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is data which meets both filters?

Comment: I think the second filter can only filter items which have passed filter1.

Comment: yes, am sure these both filters work well separetly.

Comment: As someone recently moved from backbone + rivets to angular, I'd be amazed if angular doesn't support this... [rivets](http://rivetsjs.com/) to supports nesting formatters for long time

Comment: @TarnjeetSingh Can you post the data received on success of the request.

Comment: I'll second what @VVK suggests. Seeing the data structure would be of great value here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having seen the actual dataset, this here *should* float the boat I reckon - given the properties you've exposed in your question and the nature of the loops;

https://jsfiddle.net/op7m14m1/1/

---

Instead of `for in` loops, I've opted for nested filters (which is in essence what you're doing).

```
var predicate = [];

dataset.filter(function (a) {
  var inner = a.inner.filter(function (b) {
    return predicate.indexOf(b) > -1;
  });

  return inner.length > 0; 
});
```

---

Looking at the two filters you have, you could break it down into a single function with a bound (or passed in) parameter dictating which property to use as a matcher for the filter(s).

Something like this;

```
function generic () {
  return function (prop, dataset, predicate) {
    return dataset.filter(function (element) {

      var innards = element[prop].filter(function (iEl) {
        return predicate.indexOf(iEl) > -1;
      });

      return innards.length > 0;
    });
  }
}
```

And then to use it you could do the following;

```
 module.filter('genericFilter', generic);
 module.filter('selectedDep',   generic.bind(null, 'deployment');
 module.filter('selectedTags',  generic.bind(null, 'tarn_list');

 // $filter('genericFilter')('deployment', [], ['a']);
 // $filter('selectedDep')([], ['b']);
 // $filter('selectedTags')([], ['c']);
```

---

This setup allows for a single function, that you can reuse to your heart's content - simply pass in the property you would like to do a **deep  filter** of, or bind it preemptively.